# psycopg2 install error inside virtualenv in mac

Tags: postgresql, macos, pip, virtualenv, psycopg2

I am trying to install psycopg2 using pip inside my virtualenv.
But, i am getting below error.
I already installed psycopg2-binary
but still i am getting below error.
Please suggest me a way to fic this issue.

errors:

```
    (env) ➜  bootcamp git:(master) pip install psycopg2     
    Collecting psycopg2
    Using cached psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
    Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
    Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: /Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/quinn/bootcamp/env/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/p_/fpfgyxqd4054nrz482x5z3_m0000gn/T/pip-install-td3jkgfc/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/p_/fpfgyxqd4054nrz482x5z3_m0000gn/T/pip-install-td3jkgfc/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/p_/fpfgyxqd4054nrz482x5z3_m0000gn/T/pip-wheel-ops48_8u
        cwd: /private/var/folders/p_/fpfgyxqd4054nrz482x5z3_m0000gn/T/pip-install-td3jkgfc/psycopg2/
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading pip with the following commands.

```
pip install -U pip
```

Comment: I am trying to follow up, did this solve your issue, or did it not help you at all?